# jQuery.clone() an element, then add dynamic styling to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say I have an image, `cat.jpg`, and when clicked I want to clone it.

```
$('img.cat').on("click", function() {
  $(this).clone().appendTo('#container');
});
```

Upon duplication, however, I want the new `cat.jpg` to appear as half the size of the original. And I want this to continue happening each time a new `cat.jpg` is clicked.

Any ideas on how to go about accomplishing this? Is it even possible to inject new styling/classes/parameters via `.clone()`?

Comment: After you clone an element - it's a separated DOM element you can do whatever you want to do with.

Comment: Why not head over to [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) and try it out yourself?

Comment: Been using jsfiddle.net all day and night. ;-) Just got stumped was all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the following is what you're after:

```
// If all images are within #container, use $("#container") instead:
$(document).on("click", "img.cat", function () {
    var original = $(this);
    original.clone().css({
        width: original.width() / 2,
        height: original.height() / 2
    }).appendTo("#container");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G6XTz/

Of course, you may have wanted the newly added image to be half the size of the last cat image, rather than the cat image clicked:

Fiddle2: http://jsfiddle.net/G6XTz/1/

**Caveat:**

The width and height can only divide so far; eventually you'll run into some problems. Better check the result of division first, and make a decision to do something else when it makes sense.

Comment: You posted this answer while as I was working on a CodePen illustrating essentially the same JS! Here it is, for illustration: http://codepen.io/davidtheclark/pen/JmuKg

Comment: Thank you both; this is precisely what I was looking for. I've been using jQuery's .css a lot and I don't know why I couldn't figure this out myself. Maybe brain fried. Either way, your implementation is superior to whatever I'd have come up with, for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Just setting the width to half seems to be enough with an img element, the height gets set automatically in proportion to the width:

```
$('#container').on('click','img.cat', function() {
    $(this).clone()
           .appendTo('#container')
           .width(function(i,v) { return v/2;});
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mr2x8/

But if you find you need to set the width *and* the height here's one way to do it:

```
$('#container').on('click','img.cat', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.clone()
         .appendTo('#container')
         .width($this.width()/2)
         .height($this.height()/2);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mr2x8/1/

Comment: Thank you. I would award you answer as well if I could. This works beautifully too.

Answer (score 1):

id do this:

> $(this).clone().addClass('small').appendTo('#container');

this adds the css class small to the clone of this.

Comment: The OP wants each new img to be smaller than the last, so how would creating one new class do that?

Comment: My comment above in reply to Stefanos' answer applies here as well. Thank you for posting, and I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class with the specific new styling you want to get changed dynamicaly in your CSS file.

```
.newClass {
  //example green outline
  outline: solid thin green;
}
```

And then modify your script:

```
$('img.cat').on("click", function() {
  $(this).clone().addClass('newClass').appendTo('#container');
});
```

**EDIT :**

If the only thing you want to change is the size of the img for lets say 10% each click then:

```
$('img.cat').on("click", function() {
  var width = $(this).width() * 0.9;
  var height = $(this).height() * 0.9;

  $(this).clone().css({"width":width+"px", "height":height+"px"}).appendTo('#container');
});
```

The above code will produce the same image but 10% smaller **than the image clicked** .

If you want to click only the initial image then simply put the `width` and `height` variable outside the click function and update them inside for each click.

**NOTE :**

In the `css()` you add `+"px"` if initial width is in px else you add `+"%"` if it is in percentage.

Comment: The OP wants each new img to keep getting smaller than the last, so how would creating one new class do that?

Comment: This is actually precisely what I was struggling with myself. For some reason, I too was trying to do it via classes rather than programmatically and it wasn't working out. I knew there was a better way but couldn't grasp it myself.